# "None" type params in get request

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, aiohttp

Currently building an asynchronous API wrapper using aiohttp and having an issue with request parameters where the default value is "None".

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

class AsyncWrapper:
    def __init__(self, api_key, useragent="API-Wrapper/0.2"):
        self.url = f"https://example.api/v1"
        self._api_key = api_key
        self._useragent = useragent
        self._headers = {"X-API-Key": self._api_key, "accept": "application/json", "User-Agent": self._useragent}
        self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    async def __aenter__(self):
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        await self.close()

    async def close(self):
        await self._session.close()

    async def get_endpoint1(self, arg1, arg2):
        endpoint = "/pair"

        async with self._session.get(self.url + endpoint, params={"arg1": arg1, "arg2": arg2}, headers=self._headers) as response:
            return await response.json()
    
    async def get_endpoint2(self, arg1, arg2, optionalarg1=None, optionalarg2=None):
        endpoint = "/token"

        async with self._session.get(self.url + endpoint, params={"arg1": arg1, "arg2": arg2, "optionalarg1": optionalarg1, "optionalarg2": optionalarg2}, headers=self._headers) as response:
            return await response.json()
```

`get_endpoint1` works perfectly as the existing arguments for the parameters are string type.

`get_endpoint2` however has two optional arguments for params which default to "None" (NoneType) if they are not specified.

When running this code I get:

> TypeError: Invalid variable type: value should be str, int or float, got None of type <class 'NoneType'>

In the "requests" module for Python, if you add `params` with a `NoneType`, it ignores them and doesn't encode them on the URL request.

The only option I can think to solve this issue is add a conditional check where the argument passed contains "None", and if it does, then don't add it to the `params` dict.

But I wonder if there's another approach or workaround instead. As I believe that the requests module handles this nicely.

Please feel free to add any feedback on the existing code.

Comment: I'd probably just do a condition add. There's probably something fancy that you could do, but it would likely just be messier. You could use a dictionary comprehension to filter the dictionary prior to passing it to the library.

Comment: Yup, I took that route. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use it frequently, you can create a small function like so:

```
def params(**kwargs):
    return {k, v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None}
```

And simply use it:

```py
self._session.get(
    self.url + endpoint,
    params=params(
        arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2, optionalarg1=optionalarg1, 
        optionalarg2=optionalarg2),
    headers=self._headers)
```

I think it's the cleanest you can get probably.

Comment: Yea, looks like the best way to go